# how do I associate a UISwipeGestureRecognizer with one side of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have been attempting to figure out how I can associate one UISwipeGestureRecognizer with the right half of the screen and another UISwipeGesture recognizer with the other half of the screen, however, I have been unsuccessful in coding this mechanic properly. Below is my current code. I have no idea on how I can associate one of the swipe recognizers with one half of the screen. Any help would be much appreciated

```
    -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwiped1)];

[leftSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[leftSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe1];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwiped1)];

[rightSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[rightSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe1];

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8);
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

   }
    -(void)rightSwiped1 {


SKNode *person1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person1"];

SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 80, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.2f];

[person1 runAction:moveRight];

    }
    -(void)leftSwiped1 {
SKNode *person1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person1"];

SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 400, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.2f];

[person1 runAction:moveLeft];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell; You will have to do the filtering yourself.

In the documentation for [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/) it states:

> You may determine the location where a swipe began by calling the
>   UIGestureRecognizer methods locationInView: and
>   locationOfTouch:inView:. The former method gives you the centroid if
>   more than one touch was involved in the gesture; the latter gives the
>   location of a particular touch.

For example: For the left swipe gesture you will do something like
First change your initWithTarget action selector to take an argument like this

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwiped1:)];
```

Then in your handler do something like this:

```
-(void)leftSwiped1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if(pt.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width/2))
    {
        SKNode *person1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person1"];
        SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 400, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.2f];
        [person1 runAction:moveLeft];
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible if you can vaguely go over how I will structure the code and apply locationInView? thank you for your help